# handling 4xx errors, plus login while using uiRouter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Well, I come from an `ngRoute` background, and I just started to learn `uiRouter`.

I used to write two different angular app one for login (login.html), and one for the main app (index.html). In he back-end, I just check if the user is authenticated then redirect them to index.html, else to login.html.

Now I want to encapsulate login into the main app. I have a lot of states requiring user to be logged in. In a lot of them some parts like header and footer are fixed. I'm looking for a concrete solution to handle it with these considerations:

- I don't want to use `resolve` property for all of the states which need authentication.
- I don't want my routes to be like `/some-prefix-for-authed-paths/...` for states that require authentication.
- If somebody navigates to a route which requires authentication, I want to redirect them to login page and after login I want to redirect them back into where ever they were.
- for 4xx errors, I want to display a custom error page(s) (probably route-dependent). For example if someone navigates to /users/3, and there is no user 3, (which will be determined by the resolve property of the state which will be rejected in case of not-existing user) I want to show them error page, but I **DON'T** want to change route to something like `/error` or something, because it actually doesn't make sense at all! Plus, I don't want a state push in the browser history.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement an [httpInterceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) that catches all non 2xx requests and redirect to some sort of error/login page.

Also to check for authentication you could use uiRouter onStateChange event by adding an access level to your states

```
.state('someState', {
    url: '/someUrl',
    isPrivate: true
})

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
        event.preventDefault(); 

        // Check if state is private
        if(toState.isPrivate) {
              // Do something
        }
});
```

Note! This is just somewhat pseudo code

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned in question, I don't want to **redirect** in case of error.

Comment: Oh sorry. Ofcourse you don't have to redirect when these events occurs. You can raise another event with $rootScope.$broadcast() and have some directive listen to this and manipulate the DOM accordingly.